# Can I use a yoghurt marinade in sous-vide cooking?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, sous-vide, yogurt, marinade

I want to cook a Indian-inspired chicken dish. The recipe calls for yoghurt in a marinade for the chicken. I am fine with the marinade, but I also want to cook the chicken sous-vide.

I now wonder whether the yoghurt will generate any problems when cooked sous-vide. I plan to cook it for approximately 1 hour at 60° C (but will look up in the tables to confirm). I am worried about off-smell and poor safety.

Is it safe to use a yoghurt marinade in a sous-vide recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe.  In fact, the website for the Sous Vide Supreme has a recipe for tandoori chicken that uses yogurt.  http://blog.sousvidesupreme.com/2012/06/tandoori-chicken-sous-vide/

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely safe. Just make sure the pouch is properly sealed and you select a low simmer temp, and long simmer time.

Comment: The definition of "simmer" is "just below the boiling point".  In sous vide cooking, temperatures are frequently well below boiling.